# view from layout

Tags: java, android, layout

i came across this 
http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/48845.aspx

i understand i can create a view. But i want to define a layout xml and put that into my view. for example in layout i will have a few textviews, i will set value to them dynamically and add them to view and display. is this possible if yes how ? if no whats the alternative ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Sample:

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout dialerLayout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.phone_dialer, null);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    dialerLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    LinearLayout tabDialer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabDialer);
    tabDialer.addView(dialerLayout);
```

Comment: thank you. i am relatively new to so and did not know, i will keep it mind henceforth. thanks again